# Current time as string for creating file

Tags: c++, date

So this is my function to save a file with the current name as a filename.

```
cur_date = curDate(); 
cur_date.append(".txt");
myfile.open(cur_date.c_str(), std::ios::out | std::ios::app);

if (myfile.is_open()) 
{ 
    std::cout << message; 
    myfile << message; myfile << "\n"; 
    answer.assign("OK\n"); 
    myfile.close(); 
} else 
{ 
    std::cout << "Unable to open file\n" << std::endl; 
    answer.assign("ERR\n"); 
}
```

And this is the date function:

```
const std::string server_funcs::curDate() 
{ 
    time_t now = time(0); 
    struct tm tstruct; 
    char buf[80]; 
    tstruct = *localtime(&now);

    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d_%X", &tstruct);

    return (const std::string)buf; 
}
```

My problem is, that the open() function is not creating a new file, therefore it goes to the else part of the if clause..
But when I use a different char* for the name or static input it works fine.
So I figuered it had something to do with the curDate() function, but I don't know what... Also if I print the cur_date().c_str() it displays fine..

Comment: why does `server_funcs::curDate()` return a `const std::string`? of what type id `cur_date`? please give us a compilable code..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function curDate() returns a string in the form of: "2013-10-15_19:09:02".
Because you have colons in this string, it's not an allowed filename. That's why the open function fails.

To replace the colons with dots(for example), change to the following code.
This code will specify another time format containing dots instead of colons:

```
#include <algorithm>

const std::string server_funcs::curDate() 
{ 
    time_t now = time(0); 
    struct tm tstruct; 
    char buf[80]; 
    tstruct = *localtime(&now);

    strftime(buf, sizeof(buf), "%Y-%m-%d_%H.%M.%S", &tstruct);

    std::string result = buf;
    return result; 
}
```